# NSCalibratedRGBColor chewing up memory in mosaic program

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mosaic

Firstly, I am a newbie so my thanks for your patience.

I am having a go at developing my own photo mosaic program - for me very much a learning journey.

As part of the program I am trying to enumerate through a folder of images, to calculate the average `RGB` of the images pixels, to store this data in a `NSDictionary` object and then collect the `NSDictionary` for each image in an array.

The code is a bit of a bull doze approach at the moment as I try and learn things - and I don't have any error catching built in yet.

The code works , however, when I run this through instruments I get huge allocation to a massive number of `NSCalibratedRGBColor` objects which don't seem to be released at the end of the routine.

Any thoughts/guidance on how to handle this memory issue would be welcome.

I am using the following code for calculating the average RGB.

```
while (tempFile = [dirEnum nextObject]) {

    //need to process the images within this while loop
    if ([filesAllowed containsObject:[tempFile pathExtension]]) {
        count = count + 1;
        test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", imageSourceFilePath, tempFile];
        tempFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:test];

        CIImage *sourceCIImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:tempFileURL];
        NSBitmapImageRep *tempBitmapImageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:sourceCIImage];
        NSInteger imageHeight = [tempBitmapImageRep pixelsHigh];
        NSInteger imageWidth = [tempBitmapImageRep pixelsWide];
        int totalPixels = (int)imageWidth * (int)imageHeight;

        countPixelsWide = 0;
        countPixelsHigh = 0;
        totalGreen = 0;
        totalBlue = 0;
        totalRed = 0;

        //work out averages - iterate over each column
        while (countPixelsWide < imageWidth) {
            while (countPixelsHigh < imageHeight) {
                tempColor = [tempBitmapImageRep colorAtX:countPixelsWide y:countPixelsHigh];
                [tempColor getRed:&tempRed green:&tempGreen blue:&tempBlue alpha:&tempAlpha];
                totalRed = totalRed + tempRed;
                totalBlue = totalBlue + tempBlue;
                totalGreen = totalGreen + tempGreen;
                countPixelsHigh = countPixelsHigh + 1;
            }
            countPixelsWide = countPixelsWide + 1;
            countPixelsHigh = 0;
        }

        //calculate averages - re-use total variables
        totalRed = totalRed/totalPixels;
        totalBlue = totalBlue/totalPixels;
        totalGreen = totalGreen/totalPixels;


        //create dictionary for each source image and then add to sourceImageArray for later reference
        dictOfSourceImages = [self makeDictionaryRecord:tempFileURL withAverageRed:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalRed] withAverageBlue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalBlue] withAverageGreen:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalGreen]];
        [sourceImageData addObject:dictOfSourceImages];
    }
}
```

Comment: No - i didn't resolve this issue.